# Audio Lag in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am currently working on a site which contains HTML5 canvas games. The site works fine on desktop browsers but when it comes to mobile browsers the audio file plays after 10 secs.

I have tried preloading the audio files on page load. This helped a bit but there still is a considerable lag in audio files.

Any idea as to ways to improve performance?

Comment: Can you specify which browsers on which devices? "mobile browsers" covers a lot of possibilities...

Comment: especially iphone,ipad safari browsers.